# Can't run iOS application developed using flutter

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter

Currently i'm developing a flutter app for both android and iOS. My app runs in android, but it shows error in iOS. [image: error shows in Xcode]

Code which show's error in xcode

```
else if (@available(iOS 8.0, *)) {
    BOOL success = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:options:completionHandler::[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
    result([[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:success]);
```

how can i fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the code for ios 8 into the following.

```
else if (@available(iOS 8.0, *)) {
BOOL success = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
result([[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:success]);
```

No need to add options and completion handlers.